# JavaScript array to PHP array then process in PHP and return

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Example:

javascript:

```
var mycourses=new Array(); 
mycourses[0]="History";       
mycourses[1]="Math";
mycourses[1][0]="Introduction to math";
mycourses[1][1]="Math 2";
mycourses[1][2]="Math 3";
```

PHP will then run these values through functions (please note values are mostly not strings as in the example above but rather numbers), the functions will return some text which will than be displayed in a form

How should I go about doing this?

p.s.: I found some similar stuff, but nothing quite like this... as far as I see I will have to use JSON (is there a way to code it from JS automatically - saw this for strings) and AJAX

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may use **[JSON](http://www.json.org/)** and PHP's **[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)** and **[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** functions for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries in JavaScript... that will automatically convert your Array to JSON, and in php there are function to convert from JSON to a PHP Array... you process encode again in PHP and decode in JS...

JSON is an standard for JS.. try to use it since most languages already offer support for it, and it would make your life easier

Answer (score 0):

Client-side, you need to send the data to the server and get back the result. This is a sample code with jquery, but you can do similar things with another lib or pure js:

```
$.post( "compute_courses.php", mycourses )
  .done(function( data ) {
     // Handle result
  })
  .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    // Handle error here
  });
```

This will send `mycourses` array to `compute_courses.php`, and handle the result.

Server-side, it depends which framework/lib you are using, but you will need to read the json, apply treatment, and return a result (most likely with `json_encode`). If you are planning to write that part yourself (with no third-party framework/lib), you can try something like :

```
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
$mycourses = json_decode($input, true);
// Treatment...
$json_result = json_encode($mycourses);
exit($json_result);
```

If you are looking for a PHP framework that helps to do that kind of stuff, I suggest you to use [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) or [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/).